# Qual origem do ditado "Candeia que vai à frente alumia duas vezes"?

Tags: origem-histórica, ditados, ditado-popular

Eu nunca entendi o significado deste ditado:

> Candeia que vai à frente alumia duas vezes.

Qual significado deste ditado? Qual sua origem histórica?

Comment: Não resisto: [*"Avante Camarda!"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90TJ6geLBlY)

Comment: Pois, a desbravar caminho pelas trevas - seja da noite, da ignorância, ou pela falta de liderança por mais ninguém se querer chegar à frente. Pode ser esse o sentido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minha interpretação literal do provérbio sempre foi como ilustro abaixo:

[image]

A candeia que vai à frente alumia duas vezes porque alumia o caminho à pessoa que a leva e à pessoa que vai atrás. Se fosse a pessoa de trás que levasse a candeia, já não iluminaria o caminho à da frente.

É claro que usado literalmente o provérbio não teria interesse nenhum — duas pessoas caminhando na escuridão jamais se lembrariam de ser a de trás a levar a luz. Pelo que objetivo do provérbio deve ter sido, não ser aplicado literalmente, mas ilustrar um ensinamento para aplicar noutras situações.

Aqui em Portugal, ouço o provérbio só muito raramente e também nunca compreendi claramente qual seria esse ensinamento. Então fui em busca das primeiras ocorrências escritas (reproduzo algumas abaixo), e durante o século XIX o provérbio parece ser usado para justificar agir cedo ou mesmo antecipadamente. Parece haver uma transposição do sentido literal espacial para um sentido temporal: tal como a candeia é mais proveitosa se for adiantada no espaço, certas ações são mais proveitosas se forem adiantadas no tempo. Muitas vezes a ideia é fazer a coisa agora, que já fica feita e mais tarde pode não voltar a haver oportunidade; ou fazer a pessoa interessada a coisa logo que possa, em vez de esperar que outro a faça mais tarde.

Neste exemplo de 1840, o mais antigo que encontrei, Margarida aconselha Emília a precaver-se (ou vingar-se) mandando matar certo tipo, em vez de esperar que Deus a vingue. Emília escandaliza-se (grafia original; negrito meu em todas as citações):

> Em[ília]. Vai, deixa-me: Deos ha de compadecer-se da minha infelicidade, elle me vingará.
> Marg[arida]. Quem espera çapatos de defuncto, toda a vida anda descalço.
> Em. Que? duvídas da Providencia de Deos?
> Marg. Pelo contrário; mas **candea que vai adiante alumia duas vezes** — fia-te na virgem, e não corras, e verás a sova que mamas.
> [Barbeiro dos Pobres, *O sino das duas horas, comedia original em cinco actos*, Porto, 1840](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ACoRAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA32&dq=%22candea%20que%20vai%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdgPzOgpLtAhUpyoUKHbPHCg8Q6AEwEXoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22candea%20que%20vai%22&f=false)

Neste exemplo de 1842, o provérbio vem na sequência de *principiis obsta*, ’obsta no princípio’, ou seja, “atacar o mal logo no princípio” ([Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/principiis%20obsta)). Um tipo apanhou chuva, e Michaela oferece-lhe sapatos secos:

> — Sem incommodo, tia Michaela, sem incommodo; eu não trago os pés molhados.
> — Não importa, Sr. mestre, não importa: eu bem sei o que faço. Livra-te dos ares, livrar-te-ei dos males; e, segundo diz o dictado, mais vêem quatro olhos que dous. *Principiis obsta*, dizia  meu marido de gloriosa memoria. Mestre, **candeia que vai a diante alumia duas vezes**.
> [“Variedades. Uma hora com a tia Michaela”, *Sentinella da Monarchia*, Rio de Janeiro, 5-3-1842](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=332780&pesq=%22alumia%20duas%20vezes%22&pasta=ano%20184&pagfis=438)

Nestoutro exemplo, um periódico noticia a morte de Alexandre Magno de Castilho, e este responde-lhes assegurando que ainda está vivo e mostrando aprovação por orações antecipadas pela sua alma:

> «Que isso não obste a que os bons christãos se empenhem com Deus pela boa sorte da minha alma, **pois candeia que vae adiante alumia duas vezes**.
> [*Archivo Universal*, 1860, Lisboa](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Rjk9AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA173&dq=%22alumia%20duas%20vezes%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ5YrS0I7tAhWdUBUIHRnlAOM4ZBDoATATegQIBRAC#v=onepage&q=%22alumia%20duas%20vezes%22&f=false)

Aparentemente os Castilhos gostavam deste provérbio. Temos aqui o irmão do anterior, num uso claramente sarcástico:

> […] V. S., que, mesmo sem conhecer a argumentação contraria, já vai achando materia para antecipadamente a verberar. Faz bem: **Candeia que vai adiante, alumia duas vezes**.
> [José Feliciano de Castilho, “Litteratura. Cartas”, *Constitucional*, Rio de Janeiro, 11-1-1863](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=235709&pesq=%22alumia%20duas%20vezes%22&pasta=ano%20186&pagfis=635)

Comment: Belíssima exposição Jacinto. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Está ligado à liderança, quem vai na frente ilumina o caminho para si e para os outros que o seguem.

Comment: Olá Magus, é normal pedirmos aos contribuintes que dêem um pouco mais (apesar de isto não ser a repartição de finanças). Era desejável que elabores um pouco, acrescentes umas referências à literatura, aos periódicos, até pode ser uma citação da entrevista com o presidente da junta da freguesia - mas por favor não do twitter. Isto para dizer que só uma frase, isolada, assim, *"sabe a pouco"* (no sentido do palato, não do saber). Queremos mais! Exercita a maravilhosa língua de Camões e escreve um ensaio se te apetecer. Mas não nos faças uma desfeita assim, de deixar uma frase só.

Comment: Entendido, é que eu gosto de ser sucinto. Vou enriquecer a resposta, pode deixar. Obrigado pela educação!